# Problems with callback in python dash framework. By some reason callback doesn't handling

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Thank you for the attention

I can't resolve this hidden problem during a few days and I got to the point of despair and I don't know what to do.

In my dashbroad i would like to add #1 callback which works like #2 callback. The problem is that second callback works fine, but first callback program even doesn't handling when i change value of input_database_name_SELL_vs_BUY component of course. There is no any errors :( I have checked all names and did't find any mistakes

By the way, in case of code below both callback doesn't work

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    id='layout',
    children=[
        html.H1(id="intensity_div", children='Intensity scale plot'),
        html.H3(children='Plot the intensity for the day'),
        html.Table(
            [html.Tr([html.Td(html.Table(
                # Header
                [html.Tr([html.Th('Option'), html.Th('Value')])] +
                # Body
                [html.Tr([html.Td('database name'), dcc.Input(id="input_database_name", type='text', placeholder="database name", list='datalist_of_databases', min=1, debounce=False)])] +
                [html.Tr([html.Td('day input'), dcc.Input(id="input_day", type='text', min=1, debounce=True, list='datalist_of_tables_intensity')])] +
                [html.Tr([html.Td('seconds input'), dcc.Input(id="input_seconds", type='number', placeholder="input seconds interval", min=1, debounce=True, value=1)])] +
                [html.Button(id='button_сalculate', disabled=False, children='Calculate')] +
                [html.Tr([html.Td('AVG ALL =', id='avg_all'), html.Td('AVG UPDATE =', id='avg_upd')])] +
                [html.Tr([html.Td('AVG DEL =', id='avg_del'), html.Td('AVG INSERT =', id='avg_ins')])]
            )), dcc.Graph(id='intensity_graph',)])
        ], style={'width': "100%"}),

        # SELL_vs_BUY block
        html.Table(
            [html.Tr([html.Td(html.Table(
                # Header
                [html.Tr([html.Th('Option'), html.Th('Value')])] +
                # Body
                [html.Tr([html.Td('database name'), dcc.Input(id="input_database_name_SELL_vs_BUY", type='text', placeholder="database name", list='datalist_of_databases', min=1, debounce=False)])] +
                [html.Tr([html.Td('day input'), dcc.Input(id="input_day_SELL_vs_BUY", type='text', min=1, debounce=True, list='datalist_of_tables_sell_vs_buy')])] +
                [html.Tr([html.Td('number of levels'), dcc.Input(id="number_of_levels_SELL_vs_BUY",  type='number', placeholder="500", min=0, debounce=True, step=500, value=500)])] +
                [html.Tr([html.Td('step size of level'), dcc.Input(id="step_size_of_level_SELL_vs_BUY",  type='number', placeholder="0.5", min=0.5, debounce=True, step=0.5, value=0.5)])] +
                [html.Button(id='button_calculate_SELL_vs_BUY', disabled=False, children='Calculate')]
            )), dcc.Graph(id='SELL_vs_BUY_graph',)])
        ], style={'width': "100%"}),
])

#1
@app.callback([Output('layout', 'children')],
              [Input('input_database_name_SELL_vs_BUY', 'value')],
              [State('layout', 'children')])
def get_list_of_tables_sell_vs_buy(input_database_name, old_output):
    print('1111')
    if input_database_name:
        pass
    return dash.no_update

#2
@app.callback([Output('layout', 'children')],
              [Input('input_database_name', 'value')],
              [State('layout', 'children')])
def get_list_of_tables_intensity(input_database_name, old_output):
    print('2222')
    if input_database_name:
        pass
    return dash.no_update


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, port=8051)
```

I use dash==1.21.0, i am going to use more modern version now..
In 2.0.0 it doesn't work too...

Without State it doesn't work too

I created [issue about possible bug](https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/1837)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No errors are shown because you're running with `debug` set to `False`. If you set `debug` to `True` dash tells us what the error is:

> Duplicate callback outputs
> In the callback for output(s):
> layout.children
> Output 0 (layout.children) is already in use.
> Any given output can only have one callback that sets it.
> To resolve this situation, try combining these into
> one callback function, distinguishing the trigger
> by using `dash.callback_context` if necessary.

Now I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but like the message above says, try combining your callback function or restructure your app in a way where you don't use the same output multiple times.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! Sorry for this child mistake

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Btw you can accept an answer to your question if you feel it answers your question. When you reach 15 reputation you will also be able to upvote questions and answers.